# How to configure which event custom validation method fires

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using the jQuery Validate plugin.

I have a custom validator method. It looks to see if an email address is in use.

```
$.validator.methods.notinuse = function (value, element, param) {

    $.post("/static/global/member/validation.ashx", { email: value})
    .done(function (data) {
        return data == "true";
    });
};
```

This is called like so.

```
$("#form-Registration").validate({
    rules: {
        Email: {
            notinuse: ''
        }
    },
    messages: {
        Email: {
            notinuse: "Email address in use"

        }
    }
});
```

This works, however, it appears to fire on every key touch which is a little too frequent.

My question:

1) Using a custom validator method, is there a way to configure on what event it is called? I think either on form submit or on text field focus off would do the trick. I'd like to keep it in keeping with the js query api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct format would be to set your custom method/rule to either `true` or pass a parameter, not set it to `''`.  You also misspelled your `notinuse` field name in `messages` as `inuse`.

As far as not triggering it on every key up, you could set the `onkeyup` option to false.  This will limit your method to firing only on focus out and submit click.   However, this setting will affect the all fields on the form.

```
$("#form-Registration").validate({
    onkeyup: false, // <-- disable "onkeyup" for all form fields
    rules: {
        Email: {
            notinuse: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        Email: {
            notinuse: "Email address in use"

        }
    }
});
```

---

If you want to disable `onkeyup` for *only* this one field, you can set `onkeyup` to a custom function.  In this example, if the element `name` matches `notinuse`, then there is no validation on key up, otherwise, the default `onkeyup` function is used for all other fields.

```
$("#form-Registration").validate({
    onkeyup: function( element, event ) {
        if (element.name === "notinuse") {
            return false;
        } else if ( event.which === 9 && this.elementValue(element) === "" ) {
            return;
        } else if ( element.name in this.submitted || element === this.lastElement ) {
            this.element(element);
        }
    },
    rules: {
        Email: {
            notinuse: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        Email: {
            notinuse: "Email address in use"

        }
    }
});
```

**DEMO 1 (two fields with onkeyup disabled for one field)**: http://jsfiddle.net/E9WNy/

**DEMO 2 (*your code* with onkeyup disabled for your single field)**:
http://jsfiddle.net/CJzJr/

Comment: ps, fixed typo "notinuse" from my example.

Comment: @frosty, you're welcome.  Actually, the two demos show the exact same approach.  The second demo also shows your custom method.